# PHP Welcome Screen

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Im trying to have the page say "Welcome, 'Fname of user'. Session username is the users email. The sql statement is the same from another page that works. This is the code for that page.

```
    $sql="SELECT Fname FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($_SESSION['username'])
echo "Welcome, "$rows['Fname'];    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: you might want to edit your question to remove your database password. And you might also want to add in what your problem is.

Comment: Why bother with that `if()` since your query will only ever return that user's data anyways?

Comment: Sorry i made the changes, before i had to to say Welcome, 'users email', but i wanna display their first name instead.

Comment: @TristanKrishindat - you're selecting `fname`, but you're echoing `$rows['Fname']` - PHP is case sensitive

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_query` in new applications, it's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. An alternative like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will ensure you're doing your [SQL escaping properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Lots of this code is depreciated, for example: all of the mysql_* calls should be mysqli or PDO. Be careful when making these changes though, as lots of code will need to be done a different way. Good luck :)

Comment: @andrewsi - changed fname to Fname, still have issues. Sorry i am very new to PHP, learning on the go for a school project.

Comment: @TristanKrishindat - sorry, I didn't see the error message. Your `echo` line is badly formatted. There's no closing semi-colon, and you're not concatenating the two parts correctly.

Comment: @TristanKrishindat You should not change your question and code as you fix your errors as that will render subsequent answers meaningless. If you encounter a new problem after fixing one, you should try to fix that yourself first and post a new question if you can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn basic php syntax and [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
echo "Welcome, "$rows['Fname']
```

is not correct.

You should use something like:

```
echo "Welcome, " . htmlspecialchars($rows['Fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                 ^ here
```

You also should always use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when you output to html to encode special characters like `>`, `"`, etc. that could break your html.

Comment: this is for a school project, and really didn't know any web design language prior to doing this so I'm learning and doing it the same, will definitely be looking into learning it in more detail after.

Comment: Updated the coding but still returning a error, i updated the question with the code for the whole page and error

Comment: @TristanKrishindat Please see my comment below your question. In this case, the problem is caused by the missing `}` for the `while` loop at the end.

Comment: @minitech It does not make a difference here, but I tend to use this option without thinking about it too much as I mix single and double quotes sometimes...